# Do sony headphones work on dell inspiron laptop?

Tags: dell-inspiron, headphones, mobile-phone

I have a dell inspiron laptop and a sony ericsson xperia x8. I am looking to buy earphones/headphones which are compatible with both and give good sound quality. I have always found sony earphones to be quite good, and wanted to know if they'll work on the laptop also. Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't they? Headphones are analogue for most part, and use standard TRS or TRRS connectors - if its just for sound, with no headset, there's utterly no variation in how they are wired, and nearly all are either 3.5mm or trivially convertable to alternate plug types (such as the airplane two prong, or 1/4 inch TRS). As long as it isn't a quarter inch plug (there's adaptors), any standard headphone should work with any system with no conversion.

[image]

On the left you have a standard TRS. Your Sony will have one. Your Dell will have its female equivilent. It will work. On the right there's a 1/4 inch stereo plug. This will *not* fit in your dell. There's converters for that. Its unlikely that headphones will come with *just* this - its primarily used by audiophiles and sound professionals. Its just a bigger version of the other plug anyway.

Comment: Exactly, those connectors have been around for over a hundred years, they're very compatible with pretty much everything.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Any headphones that work on the typical 3.5mm phone jack will work with the audio port on your laptop. If you buy nice enough headphones, you may find that they use a 1⁄4inch 2-conductor phone connector (like you'd plug into a guitar), but they almost always come with the 3.5mm adapter (the opposite of this is common too). You would be hard pressed to find headphones that wouldn't work with your laptop.

Comment: Some devices use 1/4 inch stereo - one of my old headphones had a screw on converter from 3.5mm to 1/4 inch, was neat enough that you couldn't tell it wasn't just 1/4 inch